# What should happen when this code is executed with input variables 0,1,2 and 3?

Tags: c++, input

My question pertains to the following code, it is a classic textbook example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()   
{
    int min{std::numeric_limits<int>::max()}; ///These two limits
    int max{std::numeric_limits<int>::min()};

    bool any(false);
    int x;

    while (std::cin >> x)
    {
        any=true;
        if (x<min)
            min = x;

        if (x)
            max=x;
    }

    if (any)
        std::cout << "min = " << "\nmax = " max << '\n';
}
```

Also, I was curious to know how to access the documentation that relates to the two limits i refer to in my comment above. Is this something that would be included in the C standard library?

Or would it be found in the documentation for the input / output streams library? In the limits library on cplusplus.com, the devs mention that the min=0, how is the max defined though? as in what are the parameters that define the max value and int could have in any C++ program?

Comment: Get a better [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). Although, nothing unclear [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).

Comment: What do you think it means? Have you tried to figure it out?

Comment: min is max and max is min. Reminds me of my student days, when one of the favorites jokes was `#define i j /* happy debugging */`

Comment: I was thinking about answering your question about "what happens" with the different inputs, but I realized that it's be too damned messy to explain. You really should just try it out and see what happens, instead. Also, you've got an error on your last line of code. You're missing a "<<". The code is also apparently *intentionally* misleading and confusing, and I don't understand why it is like that. Are we doing your homework, here?.

Comment: [Asking about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help; your professor is likely to be a better resource at this stage than Stack Overflow. If your school has a policy regarding outside help on homework, make sure you are aware of it before you ask for help on Stack Overflow. Never use code you don't understand.

Comment: @M.M. I understand. It was an attempt at humor.

Comment: @antiHUMAN thanks for your input. Not homework for a course, I wanted to learn c++ and after browsing through several textbooks I landed on Exploring C++ by Lischner. People seem to like learning from videos, but I like a good textbook. More detail and usually more difficult exercises. I'll revisit this one and test out some values.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

These two links lead you to documentation about numerical limits in the C++ standard library.

"min()" is not "zero", it's the lowest possible value depending on the type you're using. For an `int`, the value is the lowest negative number, `INT_MIN` (probably `–2147483648`), not zero. For `unsigned` types, however, it's zero.
For some types, it might mean that all bits are set to `0`, giving you the lowest possible value. For other types, it is not that simple.

"max()" is the highest possible value that the type can store. For some datatypes, it simply means that all bits are set to `1`, giving you the highest possible value. For other types, it is not that simple, but the result is always the highest possible value that the type can store/represent, nonetheless.
For `int`, the highest possible value is `INT_MAX`, which is most likely `2147483647`.

Going through your code and explaining exactly what happens, step by step, for the different input values feels out of scope, here, and sounds like I'm doing homework for you. You should try the code and see what happens.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this program checks that the number the user input fits into a C++ integer variable

Comment: @AnisAliKhan No, it doesn't do that. As it is written, that is impossible to do. The input variable is stored in an `int`, so if it doesn't fit, you'll get truncation, and you won't *know* that it didn't fit in an int. This program is basically complete nonsense.